# Federate a c++ client application with openam or opensso

Tags: c++, client-server, single-sign-on, openam, opensso

We have a c++ client application that a user authenticates and connects to the server using its credential through the client. Is there any way to implement SSO module for it to communicate with OpenAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two possible way to implement this:

- using the [C agent SDK](http://forgerock.org/downloads/openam-builds/) to perform authentication and do session management -> you may find that the C SDK isn't that pleasant and potentially too much tied to web servers in certain aspects. Also the C SDK uses the legacy OpenAM endpoints, which will potentially mean that in the future you will most likely need to adapt your code to use a newer version of the SDK that uses the REST interfaces
- use the new [REST APIs](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index.html#chap-rest) directly. The REST interfaces are still evolving though, hence they are subject of changes. In 12.0.0 there will be an API versioning solution though, which should mean that existing REST clients can remain to use the "old" version of the REST API.